# Apply rotation to Eigen::Affine3f

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

I'm using an `Eigen::Affine3f` to represent a camera matrix. (I've already figured out how to setup the view matrix/`Affine3f` from an initial "lookAt" and "up" vector)

Now, I want to support change the camera's orientation. Simple question: what's the best way to apply rotations to this `Affine3f`, i.e. pitch, yaw, roll?

Comment: Unclear. You can do that in any order you want (but results will of course not be the same). I don't think there is a "best way", depends on your goals.

Comment: Ok, forget "best way". How do I apply a "pitch" to the Affine3f assuming I already know the axis I want to pitch about and the angle that I want to pitch?

Comment: I'm very new to Eigen, so just any example of how to accumulate rotations onto an existing Affine3f would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite simple using the built in functionality. You can use an [`AxisAngle`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1AngleAxis.html) object to multiply the existing `Affine3f`. Just note that the axis needs to be normalized:

```
Vector3f rotationAxis;
rotationAxis.setRandom(); // I don't really care, you determine the axis
rotationAxis.normalize(); // This is important, don't forget it

Affine3f randomAffine3f, rotatedAffine;
// Whatever was left in memory in my case,
// whatever your transformation is in yours
std::cout << randomAffine3f.matrix() << std::endl;

// We'll now apply a rotation of 0.256*M_PI around the rotationAxis
rotatedAffine = (AngleAxisf(0.256*M_PI, rotationAxis) * randomAffine3f);
std::cout << rotatedAffine.matrix() << std::endl;  // Ta dum!!
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for.